# What algorithms are there for ANN?

Tags: ds.algorithms, near-neighbors

I'm a software engineer working on a large project for which one of the subcomponents involves approximately solving the nearest neighbors problem (to a factor of $1+\epsilon$). I was wondering what kinds of algorithms are most feasible for this problem or follow naturally from other more well-known procedures? Specifically I would like algorithms that go faster than $O(n\epsilon^{-2}\log{n})$; ideally $O(n\epsilon^{-2}\log{\log{n}})$ - cheers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximation_methods, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-neighbors, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbour